# Получить значение из Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть movie reducer

```
const initialState = {
    movies: [],
    movie: {}
};
const moviesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_MOVIES:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                movies: action.movies
            });
        case FETCH_MOVIE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                movie: state.movies[action.index]
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Есть компонент `Movies.jsx`

```
class Movies extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovies(movies) // (1);
        console.log(movies);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="movies">
                <div className="list">
                    ...
                </div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
        {
            fetchMovies: fetchMoviesActionCreator,
            fetchMovie: fetchMovieActionCreator
        },
        dispatch
    );
}

export default connect(
    state => state,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Movies);
```

Этот компонент помещает массив фильмов в хранилище см. **(1)** и выводит дочерний компонент `Movie.jsx`

```
class Movie extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovie([someIndexHere]); // (2)
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Movie component</div>;
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        movie: state.movies.movie
    }),
    {
        fetchMovie: fetchMovieActionCreator
    }
)(Movie);
```

Почему-то когда я вызываю в компоненте `Movies` `this.props.fetchMovie()` см. **(2)**,
действие `FETCH_MOVIE` в `moviesReducer` выполняется, НО в конечном этоге в `movie` я получаю `undefined`

---

При таком обработчике действия

```
case FETCH_MOVIE:
     return Object.assign({}, state, {
         movie: state.movies.length
     });
```

Я получаю вот такое значение хранилища
[image: code]

Хотя в компоненте-родителе я устанавливаю `state.movies` массивом

Если же в компоненте `Movies` вызвать эти два метода подряд, то все работает как положено

```
class Movies extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovies(movies);
        this.props.fetchMovie(2);
    }
    ...
```

[image: code 2]

Исходя из философии `Redux` насколько я понял, я могу абсолютно из любого компонента получить к данным хранилища, подключив компонент к нему функцией `connect`. Но по какой-то причине в дочернем компоненте, я получаю новую версию хранилища, которое уже не заполнено фильмами. В чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В компоненте `Movies` нужно было загружать данные не в `componentDidMount`, а в `componentWillMount`, т.к данные не успевали записываться в `store` до рендера дочернего компонента `Movie`

```
class Movies extends Component {
    - componentDidMount() {
    + componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovies(movies) // (1);
        console.log(movies);
    }
```